# Arrays dos dimensiones

Tags: javascript

Quiero hacer una mini app que te diga cuanto tiempo debe hacer cada te a partir del tipo de té y como lo haría una persona en concreto (por ejemplo, George Orwell lo dejaba unos 45 segundos menos).

Tengo dos desplegable select, a los cuales la info se añade vía un loop de javascript que los toma de un array. El problema es que el array debería incluir el nombre del té (Earl Grey, por ejemplo) pero contener un valor (en segundos) que sería lo que se sumaría en el resultado.

Actualmente, las arrays solo incluyen tiempo, ya que no se como hacer un array en el que cada campo incluye nombre mas tiempo y que esa info se agregue a las listas. Agrego el código:

```js
// Añadiendo los tipos de tea

//Escogiendo el elemento
var selectTea = document.getElementById('tea');


//Array
var teas = [180, 300, 240]


//Loop
for (var i = 0; i < teas.length; i++) {

    // creando la nueva option
    var opt = document.createElement('option');

    // Añadiendo texto al elemento (opt)
    opt.innerHTML = teas[i];

    //Añadiendo un valor al elemento (opt)
    opt.value = teas[i];

    // Añadiendo opt al final del selector (sel)
    selectTea.appendChild(opt);

}

// Añadiendo las personas

//Escogiendo el elemento
var selectPeople = document.getElementById('ho');


//Array
var people = [-50, +80, +30]


//Loop
for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {

    // creando la nueva option
    var opt = document.createElement('option');

    // Añadiendo texto al elemento (opt)
    opt.innerHTML = people[i];

    //Añadiendo un valor al elemento (opt)
    opt.value = people[i];

    // Añadiendo opt al final del selector (sel)
    selectPeople.appendChild(opt);

}

//Funcion sumar los tiempos, Number para convertir los string a numero

function totalTime() {
  var tea = Number(selectTea.value);
  var peo = Number(selectPeople.value);
  alert(tea + peo);
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
    background-color: white;
    width: 95%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 10px;
}

body {
    background-color: deepskyblue;
}

.title {
    
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    
    
}

.tea {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}

.likeho {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}

.resultado {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 100px;
    font-family: 'Roboto';
}

.desplegables {
    height: 100px;
    padding: 20px;
}

select {
    font-size: 90px;
    border: solid black 5px; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <title>Teassistant</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">


        <div class="title">
            <h1>Teassistant</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="desplegables">
            <div class="tea">


                <select id="tea" name="tea">

            </select>

            </div>

            <div class="likeho">

                <select id="ho" name="ho">
  
            </select>


            </div>
        </div>

        <div>

            <h1 class="resultado">Resultado en segundos <br>


                <input type="button" onClick="totalTime()" Value="Suma" />


            </h1>



        </div>



    </div>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que yo haría es que los elementos del array sean objetos con diferentes propiedades (nombre y tiempo) en lugar de crear un array de dos dimensiones.

Creo que así el código queda más legible:

```js
// Añadiendo los tipos de tea

//Escogiendo el elemento
var selectTea = document.getElementById('tea');


//Array
var teas = [
  {name: 'Earl Grey', time: 180},
  {name: 'Otro té', time: 300},
  {name: 'Último té', time: 240 }];


//Loop
for (var i = 0; i < teas.length; i++) {

    // creando la nueva option
    var opt = document.createElement('option');

    // Añadiendo texto al elemento (opt)
    opt.innerHTML = teas[i].name;

    //Añadiendo un valor al elemento (opt)
    opt.value = teas[i].time;

    // Añadiendo opt al final del selector (sel)
    selectTea.appendChild(opt);

}

// Añadiendo las personas

//Escogiendo el elemento
var selectPeople = document.getElementById('ho');


//Array
var people = [
  {name: 'George Orwell', time: -50 },
  {name: 'Otro personaje', time: 80 },
  {name: 'Y otro más', time: 30 }
  ];


//Loop
for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {

    // creando la nueva option
    var opt = document.createElement('option');

    // Añadiendo texto al elemento (opt)
    opt.innerHTML = people[i].name;

    //Añadiendo un valor al elemento (opt)
    opt.value = people[i].time;

    // Añadiendo opt al final del selector (sel)
    selectPeople.appendChild(opt);

}

//Funcion sumar los tiempos, Number para convertir los string a numero

function totalTime() {
  var tea = Number(selectTea.value);
  var peo = Number(selectPeople.value);
  alert(tea + peo);
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
    background-color: white;
    width: 95%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 10px;
}

body {
    background-color: deepskyblue;
}

.title {
    
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    
    
}

.tea {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}

.likeho {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}

.resultado {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 100px;
    font-family: 'Roboto';
}

.desplegables {
    height: 100px;
    padding: 20px;
}

select {
    font-size: 40px;
    border: solid black 5px; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <title>Teassistant</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">


        <div class="title">
            <h1>Teassistant</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="desplegables">
            <div class="tea">


                <select id="tea" name="tea">

            </select>

            </div>

            <div class="likeho">

                <select id="ho" name="ho">
  
            </select>


            </div>
        </div>

        <div>

            <h1 class="resultado">Resultado en segundos <br>


                <input type="button" onClick="totalTime()" Value="Suma" />


            </h1>



        </div>



    </div>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Asier! Gracias por tu respuesta y por tu tiempo. Lo usare tal como me comentas. Una pregunta... si quisiese que cada personaje, por ejemplo, tenga una cita asociada que se imprima en pantalla, la añadirías también en el array como un campo extra? Name, time y quote por ejemplo?

Muchas gracias!!!

Comment: Sí, claro. A un objeto de javascript puedes añadirle tantas propiedades como quieras. De esta forma tienes toda la información del elemento junta: nombre, tiempo, cita,....

Comment: Genial. Esto es una maravilla. Muy amable!

Answer (score 0):

Para crear Arrays de dos dimensiones, solo debes hacer que los valores del array, sean arrays:
`var matriz=[  [00,01] , [10,11], ... ];`
Para acceder a los datos indica las dos dimensiones:
`matriz[0][0]` = 00...
Por cierto, si los datos indican valores que significan cosas distintas, podrías plantearte crear un array de objetos.
`var matriz =  [ {tiempo:0, info:"info0"} , {tiempo:1, info:"info1}, ...];`
De esta manera para obtener los datos es: `matriz[0].tiempo`=0 , `matriz[1].info`="info1" ...

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta!

Answer (score 0):

Creas un array bidimensional:

```
var teas = [
  ['te1', 20],
  ['te2', 40],
  ['te3', 60]
];
```

Y luego lo llamas por posición:

```
teas[0][0] mostrará 'te1';
```

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta!